# How can i call an specific value from an array? js

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this, and I want to access `B`

```js
Elements = [['One', 'Two', 'Three'], ['A', 'B', 'C'], [1, 2, 3]]
```

How would I do this?

So far I've tried:

```js
Elements[1][1] // return undefined
```

Comment: do you have variables or strings as value in the array?

Comment: By call, to you mean that you'd like to access the value "B"?

Comment: I believe the syntax is correct, but your array is not.. try this: let Elements = [["One", "Two", "Tree"], ["A", "B", "C"], ["I", "II", "III"]];

console.log(Elements[1][1]);

Comment: The code you guys see there is an example (sorry if it wasn't a proper one), i'm adding values to the array that come form 3 variables, still, i can't get any of the values.

Comment: Maybe the issue is not in how you access the array items, but what you put into it? If what you are showing is not the real case, then consider showing the real case or cut it down to minimum (while it still results in the same issue) and show it here.

Comment: I'm putting an int and two strings on each one meaning [[1, 'string', 'string2'],[2, 'string', 'string2']]

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is correct, so the problem must be that the variables you're referencing are undefined. To test this, just try replacing `B` with a string like `'B'`.

Comment: Another useful trick is to put a `debugger;` statement right after the line in question. That will cause the browser to activate the debugger right there, and you can inspect the array and look at its values. Setting breakpoints also works, but then you have to look through the sources panel to find the right spot.

Comment: In the comments above i explained that was an example (a poor one), but thanks for marking that syntax issue, i'll edit the question right now.